# Bootstrap footer mobile display error

Tags: html, css

Im using Bootstrap to display a footer on the website however im having a display error regarding my footer when browsing using mobile devices (iPhone [Safari, Chrome], Samsung)

I find this weird, because the mobile devices pick up the rest of Bootstraps class files 100% except for the footer?

I have tried adding timestamps to the end of the css files

```
style.css?<?php echo time();?>
```

Thinking it might have been a cache issue, but that didnt work as well.

This my HTML Code

CSS Includes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Footer CSS

```
    .bs-docs-footer {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: #99979c;
    text-align: left;
    direction: ltr;
    background-color: #0d687e;
}
.bs-docs-footer-links {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bs-docs-footer-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.bs-docs-footer-links li a:hover, .bs-docs-footer-links li a:active, .bs-docs-footer-links li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.bs-docs-footer a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<footer class="bs-docs-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 0;">
    <ul class="bs-docs-footer-links">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/governance">Governance</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/resources">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/activities">Appearances</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/events">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ehna">eHNA</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/andh">ANDH</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="mbm">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/acehe" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.scharlachrot.com/images/facebook-white-256.png" width="50" height="50">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/@AfriCentre" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.scharlachrot.com/images/twitter-white-256.png" width="50" height="50">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="mbm">
        African Centre for eHealth Excellence, non-profit company registered in South Africa, Reg: 2015/218179/08
    </p>
    <p class="mbm">Directors:
        <a href="https://ehna.acfee.org/e/p/per-54d8bdbe1c694" target="_blank" style="color:#99979c;">Dr. Sean Broomhead</a>, <a href="https://ehna.acfee.org/e/p/per-54d9fb3ada591" target="_blank" style="color:#99979c;">Dr. Ousmane Ly</a>, <a href="https://ehna.acfee.org/e/p/per-54d925ac87582" target="_blank" style="color:#99979c;">Prof. Peter Nyasulu</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        Acfee &copy; 2016
    </p>
</div>
</footer>
```

**Footer on PC**

[image]

**Footer on Mobile Device**

[image]

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: **your code like this :** https://jsfiddle.net/0rrjLyc1/

Comment: Something else may be affecting your CSS, because it works in a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/ee69r9k3/embedded/result/